# Stop process in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, exit

I pretty new to this stuff and I want to ask a quick question.

I'm trying to run a sub routine which exit the whole process/code when 2 values are matched with an Access table.

Below is my main sub:

```
Private Sub btnStart_Click()
  Dim rstAddAM1 As Recordset
  Set rstAddAM1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblDeactivation", dbOpenDynaset)
  Set rstAM = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblSupervior", dbOpenDynaset)
  Dim lngID As Long

  lngID = Me.Supervior_Full_Name.Column(0)

  Debug.Print Me.Supervior_Full_Name.Column(1)
  Debug.Print Me.Supervior_Full_Name.Column(0)

    Debug.Print Me.cboEFName.Column(0)
    Debug.Print Me.cboEFName.Column(1)
    Debug.Print Me.cboEFName.Column(2)
    Debug.Print Me.cboEFName.Column(3)

Call Module6.getLeaverRequest
''Call Module6.CheckRequest

Do Until rstAM.EOF

  If rstAM![ID] = lngID Then

    Debug.Print rstAM![ID] & " Found"
    Debug.Print ""
    Debug.Print Me.Supervior_Full_Name.Column(0)
    Debug.Print Me.Supervior_Full_Name.Column(1)
    Debug.Print Me.Supervior_Full_Name.Column(2)
    Debug.Print Me.Supervior_Full_Name.Column(3)
    Debug.Print Me.RequestDate
    Debug.Print Me.cboLM
    Debug.Print Me.cboEFName.Column(0)
    Debug.Print Me.cboEFName.Column(1)
    Debug.Print Me.cboEFName.Column(2)
    Debug.Print Me.cboEFName.Column(3)
    Debug.Print Me.Status
    Debug.Print ""

    rstAddAM1.AddNew

    rstAddAM1![SuperviorID] = Me.Supervior_Full_Name.Column(0)
    rstAddAM1![Supervior_First_Name] = Me.Supervior_Full_Name.Column(2)
    rstAddAM1![Supervior_Last_Name] = Me.Supervior_Full_Name.Column(3)
    rstAddAM1![Supervior_Full_Name] = Me.Supervior_Full_Name
    rstAddAM1![LeftMove] = Me.cboLM
    rstAddAM1![RequestDate] = Me.RequestDate
    rstAddAM1![AccountID] = Me.cboEFName.Column(1)
    rstAddAM1![Employee_First_Name] = Me.cboEFName.Column(2)
    rstAddAM1![Employee_Last_Name] = Me.cboEFName.Column(3)
    rstAddAM1![Employee_Full_Name] = Me.cboEFName
    rstAddAM1![Status] = Me.Status

    rstAddAM1.Update
    rstAM.MoveLast
  Else
    Debug.Print rstAM![ID] & " Next one"
    Debug.Print ""
    rstAM.MoveNext

  End If

 Loop

 Call Module5.AddReg

 ''rstAM.Close

 Me.Supervior_Full_Name = Null
 Me.cboEFName = Null
 Me.cboLM = Null
 Me.Status = Null

 DoCmd.RefreshRecord
 Set rstAM = Nothing

 End Sub
```

it will then call on `module6.getLeaverRequest` to get the users

```
Sub getLeaverRequest()

''Looks for the supervior
Set rstAM = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblDeactivation", dbOpenDynaset)
Do Until rstAM.EOF
    If rstAM![Supervior_Full_Name] _
    = Form_frmLeaver.Supervior_Full_Name Then

        getleaverSuper = rstAM![Supervior_Full_Name]
        getleaverEmployee = rstAM![Employee_Full_Name]
        Call Module6.CheckRequest
        Exit Do
    End If
    rstAM.MoveNext
Loop
end Sub
```

Finally another call `Module6.CheckRequest` to do the check

```
Sub CheckRequest()
Do Until rstAM.EOF
    If getleaverSuper = Form_frmLeaver.Supervior_Full_Name _
        And getleaverEmployee = Form_frmLeaver.cboEFName Then
        MsgBox "Request has already been made " & getleaverSuper _
         & " " & getleaverEmployee, vbButtonType, "Can't dupibcate"
        Exit sub
    Else
    rstAM.MoveNext
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

I know this seems a bit long and I hope it helps with my issue. so to recap I want the whole process to end if 2 values match.

Many Thanks

Comment: where is the error?

Comment: I guess for me. I wanted to end Private Sub btnStart_Click oncesub checkrequest() was completed

Comment: Make called subs into functions that return a True or False to calling procedure. `If MyFunction() = True Then`

Comment: thanks for the help! that managed to work